# Getting a Static Public IP or any other workaround

Tags: networking, ip, static-ip-address

I'm developing an integration with an API which requires to whitelist customers based on IP addresses. I can easily get outbound IP from Production environments such as Azure or AWS and get those whitelisted.

How can I configure it for my desktop whose public IP keeps on changing after every few hours?

Comment: Your question is confusing... but if you trying to whitelist the incoming IP address it AWS this would be accomplished with a SecurityGroup that specified the acceptable incoming ip range. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/security-group-rules-reference.html

Don't know about Azure but I'm sure they have similar functionality

Comment: Hi @JBirdVegas, my question is, how can I get a fixed IP for my pc? :)

Comment: Thanks In understand the question now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting a fixed IP address for your home computer is dependant on your internet provider.  Sometimes they offer fixed IPs for 'Business' customers only or such.

Another solution might be to stand up an `OpenVPN` instance in your cloud then only whitelist that IP address and your expected partner prod addresses.  Then you just connect to your VPN to access your API, you can do this from anywhere as your only dependant on the IP address of the cloud `OpenVPN` instance.

This solution also scales with your development as you only need to add new `OpenVPN` users to let other developers work with you and don't need their ever changing IP addresses.

Answer (score 0):

I found an easy solution from NordVPN. It has an option to get a dedicated IP VPN :)